# Socket.io is not defined

Tags: javascript, sockets

Whenever I go to `http://localhost:8080/search` (`search.html`), it loads all of the html, then it reaches the client-side javascript and crashes. The first `console.log` in `searchClient.js` works, but not the second. The error is that io is not defined.

---

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var anyDB = require('any-db');
var engines = require('consolidate');


var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var conn = anyDB.createConnection('sqlite3://riverdata.db');

app.engine('html', engines.hogan);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function(request, response){

    response.render('home.html');

});
app.get("/search", function(request, response){
    response.render('search.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('join', function(){

    });
    socket.on('search', function(toShowList, conditionsList){
        var data = conn.query('SELECT toShowList FROM riverdata WHERE conditionsList');
        console.log("im in socket.on(search)");
        socket.emit('data', data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){

    });

});


app.listen(8080);
```

searchClient.js:

```
console.log("begins");
var socket = io.connect();
console.log("keeps running");


window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log("page loads");
    var search = document.getElementById("searchButton");
    submit.addEventListener("click", search, false);
    socket.emit('join');

    socket.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })

}, false);

function search(){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var toShowList = [];
    var conditionsList = [];

    socket.emit('search', toShowList, conditionsList);
}
```

search.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src='localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/searchClient.js"></script>
    <title>Envirostats Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="search">
    <form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="data"> Show Date <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="river"> Show River <br>
    </form>
    <button id=searchButton> Search </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: All scripts are loaded correctly?

Comment: I think so... when I run the node.js server on terminal it works properly, and it is able to read all html and javascript... the only problem is when it starts reading the searchClient.js file, it breaks on line 2.

Comment: Try with this line: <script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

Comment: using that code, every 5 seconds i get an error that says:      
GET XHR http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCb3vPy [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

Comment: Try moving

`var socket = io.connect();`

inside the window load handler

Comment: nothing changed by moving it using @SebastianLorenzo's code or mine

Comment: I don't see an `app.get("/socket.io/socket.io.js", function(...) {...});` in server.js. I don't have much experience with programming with node.js, but, might this be part of the problem?

Comment: Try to change <script src='localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script> to this <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>